# Using AWS ECS service tasks as disposable/consumable workers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, queue, jobs, amazon-ecs

Right now I have a web app running on ECS and have a pretty convoluted method of running background jobs:

I have a single task service that polls an SQS queue. When it reads a message, it attempts to place the requested task on the cluster. If this fails due to lack of available resources, the service backs off/sleeps for a period before trying again.

What I'd like to move to instead is as follows:

Run a multi task worker service. Each task periodically polls the queue. When a message is received it runs the job itself (as opposed to trying to schedule a new task) and then exits. The AWS service scheduler would then replenish the service with a new task. This is analogous to gunicorn's prefork model.

My only concern is that I may be abusing the concept of services - are planned and frequent service task exits well supported or should service tasks only exit when something bad happens like an error

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to kill the ECS task after it has completed the job? Why not leaving it running so it can process more incoming jobs without restarting? This is what Celery does for example.

Comment: @dukebody, I will have several people writing these jobs. I am not convinced that they will avoid modifying constant/static data. If I don't restart the task then this modification will incorrectly persist across jobs. IMO the only safe thing to do is to nuke the job when its done and let it restart

Comment: Have you considered sandboxing with something similar to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython, or AWS Lambda?